# Mongo bulk insert не создает новую database

Tags: golang, mongodb

Добрый день, опишу суть с самого начала.
У монгоДБ когда делаешь первый инсерт в database, collection  они создаются с нуля. Вопрос почему когда делаешь bulk.insert он пишет ошибку not found. И как с этой проблемой бороться. 
Как решить проблему не прибегая к костылю?

Вот маленький кусочек кода в котором и есть сама загвоздка.

```
bulk := self.Database.C(self.get_collection_name()).Bulk()
bulk.Unordered()
for _, doc := range trades{
    bulk.Insert(doc)
}
gg, err := bulk.Run()
fmt.Println(gg, err)

if err!= nil{
    if !mgo.IsDup(err) {
        return false
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

А вот вывод строчки  `fmt.Println(gg, err)` `<nil> not found`

Вот скрин всех баз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаем обычный инсерт а не булк `mongo.Mongo.Session.DB("test").C("test").Insert(a{"asd"})`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась , у меня в название базы была **точка**. Тобишь

`b := mongo.Mongo.Session.DB("testDB.com").C("qwe").Bulk()`

Когда ее убрал все стало на свои места и заработало. 
Спасибо кто помог.